# why does socket.io client emit trigger its own listener...even if server is offline?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I ran into a weird problem when using socket io after many years.
Years ago, I could use the following code on client side

```
socket.emit('user', {userId: 2});
// and somewhere else in the code id listen for incoming 'user' replies
socket.on('user',(reply) => {
    // do something with user data received from server
});
```

Now, when I have the same code on the client side, and I emit "user" request, the socket.on('user') callback is immediately fired with request payload which was supposed to go to the server( which is offline ).

I thought socket.on() listeners were triggered only by replies from the server and not by the outgoing messages from the client itself.

Is the socket.io supposed to work like this or am i missing something in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this by accidentally stumbling on another post about how socket.io keeps the connection alive.

The socket.emit('user', {userId: 2}); was an example. 
In my real app, I used the event name "ping" which seems to be reserved by socket.io.
The client keeps pinging and listening to pings constantly.

So, when I added my own socket.on('ping') listener, it hooked into socket.io internal ping/pong system. ( at least i think thats the case )

Comment: But isn't the ping event it's listening for still supposed to be coming from the server?

Comment: I thought so as well, but looks like its an exception of some kind...or my setup is messed up. either way, all other events, except for ping, work fine.